# an example in <thinking in java>,it seems not work

Tags: java

```
class Candy{
    static {
        System.out.println("Loading Candy");
    }
}
class Gum{
    static {
        System.out.println("Loading Gum");
    }
}
class Cooki{
    static {
        System.out.println("Loading Cooki");
    }
}

public class SweetShop {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("inside main");
        new Candy();

        try {
            Class.forName("Gum");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't fide Gum");
        }
        System.out.println("After Class.forName(\"Gum\")");
        new Cooki();
        System.out.println("After create Cooki");
    }
}
```

/Output:

inside main
     Loading Candy
     Couldn't fide Gum
     After Class.forName("Gum")
     Loading Cooki
     After create Cooki

this is my code and result,Gum is not found.

---

an Rtti example for java,in the book ,the result is:

```
inside main
Loading Candy
Loading Gum
After Class.forName("Gum")
Loading Cooki
After create Cooki
```

It seems Class.forName() not working,it is not intialize Gum.

Comment: `Loading Gum` is in your output, though.

Comment: Do you use the default (root) package?

Answer (score 0):

```
    package test;

class Candy {
    static {
        System.out.println("Loading Candy");
    }
}

class Gum {
    static {
        System.out.println("Loading Gum");
    }
}

class Cooki {
    static {
        System.out.println("Loading Cooki");
    }
}

public class SweetShop {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("inside main");
        new Candy();

        try {
            Class.forName("test.Gum");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't fide Gum");
        }
        System.out.println("After Class.forName(\"Gum\")");
        new Cooki();
        System.out.println("After create Cooki");
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to provide the complete package like in above code "test" is the package and "Gum" is class name. So you need to write *Class.forName("test.Gum");*